# How to prevent showing PDO error?

Tags: php, pdo

When there is an error from PDO execute(), for some reason it outputting the error?

How do I prevent that.... I would like to store an error into $data['error']

```
if (!$query->execute()) {
             $data['success'] = 'false';
             echo json_encode($data);
             return;
}
```

From Console Log:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute() [<a href='pdostatement.execute'>pdostatement.execute</a>]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in <b>C:\wamp\www\site\application\controller\ContactController.php</b> on line <b>101</b><br />
{"success":"false"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine what the two other anwsers say, first set PDO to use exceptions instead of php errors :

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then use a try... catch block to handle any error.

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try{
  /* Do your database things here */
}
catch(Exception $e){
  $db->rollBack();
  return;
}
$db->commit();
return;
```

You could also setup your own php error handler which could be used to log all errors in a file and not display anything.
See the php documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 2):

You can change the error mode to your liking, e.g.:

```
$conn = new PDO(...);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Please find further reference at http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's try catch

```
try{
     doPDO();
}
catch (PDOException $err) {
     echo "pdo failed";
}
```

Comment: It's a E_WARNING, so a `try ... catch` block won't catch anything.

Comment: Indeed I missed that point. Sorry. Indeed the above answer is the one ;). Thanks alix