# don't show warnings to the client when using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I noticed that PDO displays warnings to the end client. For example, if an invalid enum value is being set, it shows a warning:

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1

There is no reason for end user to see this. I'd much rather just display `500` status code, although it is users fault so 400 would be more appropriate.

These are my current pdo options:

```
public static array $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
```

and i am using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

at the top of the script.

Any idea why this is happening?

Minimal code with intentional incorrect values when `display_errors` is set to 1:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (`type`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([$json->type]);
```

Full message without stack trace

> SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1
>   **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 in path/api/v1/index.php:35

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent showing PDO error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817705/how-to-prevent-showing-pdo-error)

Comment: Are you sure that "ini_set('display_errors', 0);" actually affects the configuration? On some servers, it would be ignored.

Comment: @MarkOverton I have already set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Warning is still displayed.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Yes, if I set it to 1, than the message also contains the fatal error.

Comment: Can you provide the **full** error message? As well as a code fragment that produces this error

Comment: As the message error says, you need to Increase the length of your column to fit the length of the data you are trying to insert

Comment: It doesn't seem to me similar to this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682621/pdoerrmode-exception-doesnt-suppress-warning). More like some handler is catching the error, echoing the message and re-throwing the exception. Can you reproduce it in a standalone script?

Comment: @YourCommonSense aah you are right indeed. Somewhere in the middleware stack I indeed echo the error and rethrow it.